not able to install angular cli on command prompt
I used the command npm install -g @angular/cli on the command prompt to install Angular CLI, but it just keeps loading for a very long time and is not getting installed. Can anyone help me with this?
I tried the command npm cache clear , for which I got the following result:
npm error As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
npm error   by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
npm error   data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
npm error   want to make sure everything is consistent, use npm cache verify
npm error   instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
npm error   not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
npm error
npm error   On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
npm error   or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
npm error   cache, you can use npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache to use a
npm error   temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm error
npm error   If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm error   with --force.
Then I tried the command npm cache clean --force, for which I got the following result:
npm warn using --force Recommended protections disabled.
